# iOS - Unable to build, header missing (although present in folder)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I installed HTMLKit via pods.

Everything went well and I am able to see it loaded.

Unfortunately, when I try to build the project, it fails telling me that it couldn't find a specific header.

This is how I import the pod in my file:

`#import "../../../Pods/HTMLKit/Sources/HTMLParser.m"`

I am no expert in objective c so I am not sure if that's correct. One thing that is weird is that I always imported header files, but this time it seems that I need to import an `.m` file?

If I try to import the header file of that, it simply says that the header is not found (although, as always it's there in the folder).

I am not sure how to fix it. I've seen some answers here on SO but they all use a different version of xcode so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: never import an .m file. CocoaPod frameworks are usually imported like this: `#import <HTMLKit/HTMLParser.h>` or even just `#import <HTMLKit/HTMLKit.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try #import  <>
And if it show you something automatically I think it will work.

Again, Not “”.  Use <>.